# Google combo chart not displaying candlesticks with stepped area when using hAxis ticks

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

When I use combo chart and use mixture of candlesticks and stepped aria chart with hAxis ticks,
it doesn't render candlesticks chart and only displays the stepped area.
I want to break the steps on vertical grids on candles but don't know how to do it.

This is my code:

```
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Date',     'Low', 'Open', 'High', 'Close', 'Average'],
            [{v:1, f:"2014/05/01"},   200,   300,    500,    400 , 100],
            [{v:2, f:"2014/05/02"},   300,   400,    600,    700 , 200],
            [{v:3, f:"2014/05/03"},   100,   150,    200,    300 , 400],
            [{v:4, f:"2014/05/04"},   100,   150,    200,    300 , 400]
        ]);

        var options = {
            areaOpacity: 0,
            bar: { groupWidth: '60%' },
            series: {
                0: {type: "candlesticks"},
                1: {type: "steppedArea"}
            },
            hAxis: { ticks: [{v:1, f:"2014/05/01"},{v:2, f:"2014/05/02"},{v:3, f:"2014/05/03"},{v:4, f:"2014/05/04"}]}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```